# $g(x) = 1- \sqrt{x+2}$ For which $x \in \Bbb R $ is $g(x)$ positive?

Tags: functions

What happens when $x < -2$ ? Does the whole square root term just "disappear" which leaves us with 1 which is positive and thus the answer to the question is $x\le-1$? Or do we have to constrain the domain of $x$ to: $(-2\le x\le-1)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, your function g is defined only for $x \geq -2$, just because we're in Real domain and here we do not allow the square roots of negative numbers.

So we need to establish for what $x \geq -2 $, we have $g(x) > 0 $

That means:

$1-\sqrt{x+2} > 0$

$1 > \sqrt{x+2} $

Since both sides of inequality are positive, we can square it by sides, getting:

$1 > x+2 $

$ x < -1 $

So the answer is $x\in[-2,-1) $

Answer (score 3):

When $x<-2$ then $g(x)$ is not defined. The square doesn't just disappear; the whole thing simply doesn't make sense. In this case $g(x)$ is not positive, or negative, or anything: it doesn't exist!  So the domain is indeed $[-2,-1)$.